# Is it possible to have a model with both a one-to many and a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a system where I will have Products (classes) that can be taught by one or more Instructors.  These Instructors can also *create* Products in which case they should be accessible via the Product as its Developer.  However, I also want to be able to access *all* of the Instructors who are available for that product.

I am not sure how to set the SQLAlchemy models up so that I can just have a one-to-many relationship for `Product.developer` but a many-to-many relationship for `Product.instructors`.

models.py

```
from app import db

instructors = db.Table('instructors',
    db.Column('instructor_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('instructor.id')),
    db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
)    


class Instructor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    #courses qualified for etc

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    courseName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    developer = db.relationship('Instructor', secondary=instructors,
        backref=db.backref('developed', lazy='dynamic'))
    instructors = db.relationship('Instructor', secondary=instructors,
        backref=db.backref('products', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category> %r>' % (self.courseName)
```

views.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app, models

@app.route('/product/<courseName>')
def show_product(courseName):
    product = models.Product.query.filter_by(courseName=courseName).first_or_404()
    return render_template('show-product.html', product=product)
```

template: show-product.html

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<br><b>Course Name:</b> {{product.courseName}}
<br><b>Curriculum developer:</b> 
    {% for developer in product.developer %}
        {{developer.name}}
    {% endfor %}
<br><b>Lead Instructor:</b> 
<br><b>Certified Instructors:</b> 
    {% for instructor in product.instructors %}
        {{instructor.name}}&nbsp;
    {% endfor %} 


{% endblock %}`enter code here`
```

this is the code that I am running to put a value in the database.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import db, models

instruct1 = models.Instructor(name="instructor1")
db.session.add(instruct1)
db.session.commit()

instruct2 = models.Instructor(name="instructor2")
db.session.add(instruct2)
db.session.commit()

dev = models.Instructor(name="developer")
db.session.add(dev)
db.session.commit()

prod = models.Product(courseName = "test")

prod.instructors = [instruct1]
prod.instructors.append(instruct2)

prod.developer = [dev]

print "Instructors:"
for instructor in prod.instructors:
    print instructor.name

print "Developer"
for i in prod.developer:
    print i.name

db.session.add(prod)
db.session.commit()
```

And here is the output:

```
Instructors:
instructor1
instructor2
Developer
developer
```

But when I view the web page I see:

```
Course Name: test 
Curriculum developer: instructor1 instructor2 developer 
Lead Instructor: 
Certified Instructors: instructor1  instructor2  developer
```

Update: Thanks doobeh! I updated my code, http://bpaste.net/show/o8PtsY3Kvu8bxKnDEo24/ but when I run the python code I get the error "Error creating backref 'products' on relationship 'Product.instructors': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Instructor|instructor'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your problem will evaporate if you just create your developer relationship correctly.  At the moment, you've copied the relationship from the many-to-many one you're using.  So your developers are being added to the same stack as the instructors-- the reason why you don't see it immediately is because you've not committed it to the database until after you just print out the lists again.  As soon as you commit those lists to the database, and re-query, you'll get the multiples you're seeing in the template.

I think if you changed your `Product` model to be:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    courseName = db.Column(db.String(64))

    developer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey='instructor.id'))
    developer = db.relationship('Instructor', backref='develops')

    instructors = db.relationship('Instructor', secondary=instructors,
        backref=db.backref('products', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category> %r>' % (self.courseName)
```

It would work as you expect (untested code!). Since you're storing just a single developer on each `Product` now, you won't need to iterate over those values, or pass in a list/append when your adding them in.

To make it clearer about why you can't have multiple many to many joins
using the same fields, lets break down what's happening on a SQL level.

Your M2M join table `instructors` has two fields, `instructor_id` and
`product_id`. You then create three instructors:

```
id:1    instructor1
id:2    instructor2
id:3    developer
```

Then you create a product:

```
id:1    product
```

If I add those first two instructors to that product, the `instructors` 
link table will store the information like:

```
product_id      instructor_id
1               1
1               2
```

Then you add in the developer to the same table:

```
product_id      instructor_id
1               1
1               2
1               3
```

So when you say "Give me all the instructors of this product" SQLAlchemy is
going to ask the model, "Hey, I've got a relationship here showing that products
are linked to instructors in the `instructors` table, so give me all the instructors
that have a product id of 1" and of course you'll get three results, not just the two you expected and you get the same three when you ask for developers because it's using the same linkages.

If you wanted to create two many to many joins, you'd just have to create a second link table called `developers` or similar, which holds just the information pertinent to that relationship.  But, in this case, because you just want a single developer linked to a product, you can just use a simple`ForeignKey` to map that relation.

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/o8PtsY3Kvu8bxKnDEo24/ when I run the python code I get the error "Error creating backref 'products' on relationship 'Product.instructors': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Instructor|instructor'

Comment: You're quite right, but knowing the error you should be able to identify the problem-- that there's still a collision. I added a backref called `products` that linked the developer to the `Product` but there was already one called `products` linking the instructors to the products.  If you rename the backref to something unique, perhaps `develops` makes semantic sense, then it will work.  I'll adjust the above code.  @SeanVieira thanks :)

Comment: @Doobeh I had to set the lazy to 'select' because I got the error "SAWarning: On relationship Product.developer, 'dynamic' loaders cannot be used with many-to-one/one-to-one relationships and/or uselist=False."